# Can and should constructors do more work than merely assigning values to fields?

Tags: object-oriented, class, constructors

A typical introductory example to OOP, classes, and constructors is `object Car`, with properties such as `float fuel`, `bool is_engine_running`, etc etc, and a class and constructor definition might be as follows (I'm using a Java-esque syntax here, but it works in any OOP language):

```
class Car {
    float fuel_remaining;
    bool is_engine_running;
    // ... other fields

    Car(float fuel, bool is_engine_running, ...) {
        this.fuel_remaining = fuel;
        this.is_engine_running = is_engine_running;
        // Other assignments
    }
}
```

Most examples of *constructors* I've seen (admittedly not many, as I haven't dug through the sources for large Java/C++ projects yet) tend to do simple `this.x = x` assignments. I would like to implement a class representing UUIDs (I know there already exists various built-in/third-party libraries dealing with this; this is a custom namespace-based UUID for a client with specific requirements) with the UUID itself internally represented as a 128-bit (or 32-byte) array. I am considering C++'s `std::bitset<128>` for this, or any equivalent in other languages.

When I initialise the UUID object, I would think that valid constructors would accept, amongst others, the current time, the variables (typically strings) from the namespace, some hardware address (also possibly a string), or even a UUID string itself; for instance, `"9fbaea6e-a929-4833-a802-9d64ac432126"`. Otherwise, I would have to directly provide a bit/byte array for the constructor to do something like `this.uuid_bits = uuid_bits`, which I feel is rather pointless, because it removes any abstraction whatsoever and leaks the internal bit-array representation to the caller.

Therefore, my question is this: The above UUID class will require some string-parsing, bit-shifting, etc to *properly* initialise any object while still abstracting away the internal representation. Is it hence an *anti-pattern* to do *more* work than merely trivial assignment in the constructor? If not, how might I separate out this 'extra work'? Would I perhaps write and use `private static` functions/methods to further process the arguments to the constructor, and return the appropriate internal representation, so that the constructor itself only does an assignment?

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on your class, what it does, how you expect to use it, and what kind of performance optimization you're looking for.

If you're looking for the constructor to trigger some external work, e.g. a cleanup of the file server, that is not appropriate. But I suspect you're thinking more along the lines of calculations of values that are relevant to the currently constructed class' lifetime.

The first approach is to calculate your values once, in the beginning. This means that you don't have to repeat the same calculation whenever the data is requested.

For the examples, I'm going to use taking the first letter of a string as "the calculation". It's of course a trivial amount of effort, but it's merely intended as a simple example of a value calculation of any level of complexity.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public char FirstLetterOfName { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.FirstLetterOfName = name[0];
    }
}
```

This is straightforward, and leads to increased performance on repeated usage, at the cost of initial performance when initializing the object.

The second approach is to defer the execution of the value until it is asked. This means you don't waste time during initialization, especially if you never end up fetching this specific value. But if you fetch the specific value multiple times, you'll lose performance by redoing the same calculation.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public char FirstLetterOfName
    { 
        get { return this.Name[0]; }
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

The third approach tries to have it both ways: deferred execution, and caching the result so the execution is not repeated.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private char? _firstLetterOfName;
    public char FirstLetterOfName
    {
        get
        {
            if(_firstLetterOfName == null)
                _firstLetterOfName = this.Name[0];

            return _firstLetterOfName;
        }
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

This approach maximizes performance both during initialization and during repeated usage, but it comes at the cost of a more complex implementation, which affects readability and maintainability, in a "straw that broke the camel's back" sense.

---

So, depending on which approach you take, you can enhance:

1. Performance during initialization
2. Performance during repeated usage
3. Code readability and maintainability

You can't have it all, but you can have **two out of three**. Take your pick.

- 1 + 2 => third approach
- 1 + 3 => second approach
- 2 + 3 => first approach

Comment: " I would like to implement a class representing UUIDs"

Comment: @Ewan "For the examples, I'm going to use taking the first letter of a string as "the calculation". It's of course a trivial amount of effort, but it's merely intended as **a simple example of a value calculation of any level of complexity**."

Answer (score -1):

Problems with logic in constructors:

1. It's considered bad practice for constructors to throw exceptions
2. Constructors are not inherited, so you cant mock or dependency inject them
3. Calling code often doesn't control when they are called eg deserialisation or binding
4. They are not optional, so lists of objects or copies etc are problematic

However, in your case you have a reasonably good argument for a constructor. The logic will be a simple function of the input parameters, unlikely to throw exceptions, unlikely to require inheritance or injection etc.

Although, if we check what microsoft does, they go with the static method approach

```
Guid.NewGuid()
```

This suffers from lots of the same issues, but again there is a clear spec for Guids that's unlikely to change in a breaking way and there is precedence for such things in `Math.Whatever()` functions.

Probably the best way to go is to have a builder object

```
var b = new GuidV3Builder();
var guid = b.Generate(params);
```

Now you can separate the various versions, have a testable interface, obey SOLID and also have a clear way to implement things like sequential GUIDS

Comment: The arguments listed are a bit, well,  arguable. (1) There is a subset of developers who favor never allowing an invalid state to exist, e.g. if `1234` is not a zip code, then `new ZipCode("1234")` shouldn't pretend like it is. (2) Constructors are uniquely scoped to only their class, they have no shared nature. Inheritance makes no sense here, nor does mocking. Using a real class requires a real constructor, as per the purpose of a class' constructor. (3) Calling code doesn't know the logic behind properties either but that's not an argument against having _some_ logic in a property.

Comment: 1. they are wrong 2. exactly, this is a problem if you want to test something that depends on that logic or inject it. 3. it is

Comment: (1) Try justifying your position instead of just claiming anyone who doesn't agree with you is wrong. (2) If you ever think to yourself "I need this constructor to be mocked while using the actual class itself", then you've got a really skewed idea on what the purpose of a constructor is. And as far as injection goes, hence the constructor parameters? (3) Same as (1). Note that I said _some_ logic. For example, a simple null check, or a simple cleaning algorithm (for e.g. profanity, whitespace tidying, ...). I didn't say "any logic, no matter the size or complexity".

Comment: 1. zipcode validation changes. you cant read any of the old zipcodes from your database because the constructor fails. 2. the point is you want to be able to swap out the logic, tightly coupling to the class prevents this. 3. you admit its a problem with big logic, but its not a matter of length of code is it, you could have a single problematic line. Hence any logic is "problematic" ie a potential problem.

Comment: (1) It makes no sense to want to parse invalid values when already applying the hardline stance that you refuse to acknowledge their existence. You're pointing out how a half-applied rule is inconsistent, which is tautological (2) Tight coupling is irrelevant for a constructor, by definition of what a constructor is. The point of a constructor is to have _rigorously fix_ the required initialization logic. If any subset of that logic is swappable or injectable, that's what you have constructor parameters for. (3) You seem to have glossed over me mentioning "size **or complexity**".

Comment: To further extend (2), there is also no possibility of swapping out the implementation of a specific method of a class, while still using that concrete class as the type you're working with, so it makes no sense to then turn around and expect constructors to somehow accommodate this. The entire point of defining a class method is to tie the method's implementation to the specific class you're declaring it in - and constructors are no different here. Inheritance, which is using a **different* type, makes sense for class methods but not for class constructors, which are inherently locally scoped

Comment: 1. there's no point in applying a hardline stance when reality changes over time. Put the same logic in a parsing class and you are golden

Comment: 2. if the logic is in a constructor (or static method)) then you are forcing a consuming class to tightly couple to the class in question. If you put the logic in a method you are golden

Comment: 3. I used short circuit evaluation on your OR

Comment: (1) In general, not every codebase change is inherently capable of handling an outdated database structure For example, when a previously nullable field is now considered to be non-nullable. In those cases of data incompatibility, you're always forced to have to clean up the data to maintain compatibility. In a system where valid zip codes are rigorously enforced, where the validity of that zip code suddenly changes, a change to the old data is inevitable (assuming there are entries which passed the old logic but not the new one).

Comment: (2) **Any** instantiation of any class is inherently bound to its constructor(s). That is precisely what the purpose of a constructor is, to explicitly define the only possible ways of instantiating said class. This is nothing new. You are conflating constructors with general class methods, but constructors have a different conceptual meaning and therefore expectation. It makes no sense to want to instantiate a `Foo` object without passing by (one of) its `Foo` constructor(s)

Comment: 1. well exactly, but putting the parse logic in the constructor stops you doing that. you are forced to move it out to some other class

Comment: (3) Witty as you may be, you even used the wrong short-circuiting logic then.

Comment: _"you are forced to move it out to some other class"_ The point I just made is that there are _some_ changes that can be made to a data model that inevitably make the class incompatible of loading in the old data. This inherently forces you to fix the data without involving said class, _before_ the class can load it again. There is no way to make a class that is 100% guaranteed to be able to handle _any_ old version of its previous structure. The simplest example here: trying to make a previously nullable field non-nullable. It can't be done without old data (with nulls) becoming incompatible.

Comment: 2. OK i concede my argument for point 2 is incorrect.

Comment: I also want to point out here that I'm not saying that your approach doesn't work for some developers, I am saying that it isn't a _blanket_ rule for _all_ developers, and should not be used as a blanket rule to exclude certain approaches that would fit for the use case of those developers you just excluded. There is definitely value in allowing invalid values and validating them at a later stage, but that is not the universal rule for everyone.

Comment: 3. i don think so, but the point stands, you could have a single complex operation, or at the very least be forced to check for complexity. even your simple example of initial leaves out TrimI()

Comment: 1... in those changes a non hardcore approach is to allow the class to accept both versions of zipcode

Comment: _even your simple example of initial leaves out TrimI()_ Whether a particular code snippet does a calculation directly or passes it off to some submethod is irrelevant in terms of computational complexity.

Comment: exactly my point, putting logic in properties == bad

Comment: There is a recurring pattern here where your advice definitely has merit, but is then preached as the only true word and used to argue that anything else is therefore wrong. It is the latter part that I'm responding to, not the original advice itself. You are glossing over use cases or development practices that you're not accounting for, and then concluding your advice by wrongly excluding these unaccounted cases. I am not saying your advice is inherently wrong, but you are applying it much too broadly.

Comment: I literally say "However" and detail exceptions in the second paragraph. The problem is that you are overly worried about telling people when they are wrong. (except me :))

Comment: the third paragraph discusses a popular alternative and the fourth gives my overall advice

Comment: _"I literally say "However""_  To pick one of the points, you said "however, you are unlikely to throw exceptions", which is not a counter to the fact that "throwing exceptions in constructors shouldn't happen" is overapplied advice. You're forcing a dichotomy of "exceptions are bad, no exceptions are good", which still inherently excludes any approach where the exceptions are explicitly desired.

Comment: I don't even think you disagree with the list of "problems" If i had put "some people think..." and "potential issues" or  and few more "maybes" we prob wouldnt have had this argument

Comment: well if you dont throw exceptions because everything is perfectly tested you dont throw exceptions?

Comment: _"If i had put "some people think..." and "potential issues" or and few more "maybes" we prob wouldnt have had this argument"_ Yes, because then your advice wouldn't be preached as if it's a universal truth. _Some_ people do indeed want to avoid constructor exceptions. _Maybe_ this applies to OP. I 100% agree with that. My issue is not that your advice is allegedly never correct (which isn't the case), my issue is that your advice pretends to be universally correct, which it isn't.

Comment: If i didnt think it was correct I wouldnt post it. I dislike your style of answer because its over long, vague and unhelpful. I write i my style because that the kind of answer i want when searching. direct, to the point and practical. Being short means that yes there will be some generalities in there, but going into the detail on exceptions in constructors or whatever isn't helpful. Knowing that they are considered bad is.

Comment: Sure it might mean i pickup a down vote or two from people who are triggered by the first sentance "OMG EXCEPTIONS IN CONSTRUCTORS ARE AMAZEBALLS! THIS GUY IS AN IDIOT!!" but if you want actual advice on 'the best' way to write your GUID class then its right there in black and white. It doesnt need a *warning internet ppl may be wrong small print